# including boost library, prevent print to console

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost, boost-asio, eclipse-cdt

I install boost library and i want to test it. I build and run the following project. But i have a problem. When i build project:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build 

g++ -std=c++0x "-IC:\\boost\\include\\boost-1_68" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 
     -o "src\\MyTestProject.o" "..\\src\\MyTestProject.cpp" 

g++ "-LC:\\boost\\lib\\" -o MyTestProject.exe "src\\MyTestProject.o" -lws2_32 
     -llibboost_iostreams-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 
     -llibboost_filesystem-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 
     -llibboost_system-mgw63-mt-x32-1_68 

Build Finished. 0 errors, 0 warnings.
```

After i click run project: "Info: Nothing to build for MyTestProject" and it doesn't print anything to MyTestProject.exe console.

If i comment out <boost/asio.hpp>, it prints "Hello world!". What is the problem? I'm using mingw-64, eclipse CDT, boost_1_68_0 on windows. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
//#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  //boost::asio::io_context io;
  //boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  //t.wait();

  cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl; 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My first step would be to try and build and this from the console (using the commands that eclipse has logged) and see what happens.

Comment: I do but there is no error @john

Comment: So do you get an error return when you run the program? Only explanation I can think of is that your program crashes before it gets a chance to print anything, and presumably that is happening when some boost library initialises itself.

Comment: yes john thank you. I find the solution. It cannot find the .dll file. I add it to project and it works. Thank you @john

Answer (score 1):

i find the solution. I add libboost_system-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_68.dll file to my project directory(..\Users\workspace\MyTestProject). Actually, i have already added -L c:\boost\lib and -l libboost_system-mgw63-mt-d-x32-1_68 into linker. Also boost is added to PATH. I don't know why it cannot find the dll, but for now i solved problem in this way.

Comment: So, did you understand what was happening? The problem was not that console output didn't happen. Instead, the problem was that the whole program could not be started. There are different ways to distribute DLLs with your application, but putting them in the same directory as your executable is by far the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

When you print to the console and immediately return, there is a chance that the console will disappear without giving you a chance to read anything.  Try reading an acknowledgement from `cin` afterwards.
Also, you should always say `if (cout)`, otherwise you do not know if the stream failed.

Comment: i try this but again i get same result. If i dont include asio.hpp, it works perfectly. But if i include asio.hpp, program is terminated and i cannot pass cin value;

Comment: You can never pass a value to `cin`, it passes values to you.